# Automating mysqldump with PDO PHP, is it possible?

Tags: php, apache, pdo, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple page with two buttons than, when one of them is pressed the database is dumped (`mysqldump`) and with the other is restored (imported).

I'll try to do that for one development environment, I don't have a centralized server and, on occasions I found myself working from several different PCs according to the day and situation, the scripts itself (i.e. the code) I just sync with SpiderOak, and I'm trying to make the mysqldump to do the same between PCs.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Herramienta Back Up/Restore DataBase ;)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Babifu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/450/370/nightlife/"/><br /><br />
        <form id="me1" action="backup.php" method="post"><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Backup database" />
        </form>
        <form id="me2" action="restore.php" method="post"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Importar" />
        </form>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

backup.php

```
<?php
include('conection.php');
try {
    $qls = "mysqldump --default-character-set=UTF8 --single-transaction -u root -p[Paswordofthedatabase] u739462586_dtren > restoresync.sql";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($qls);
    $rslt = $stmt->execute();
    echo "Base de Datos Salvadas Correctamente";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage;
}
?>
```

restore.php

```
<?php
include('conection.php');
try {
    $qls = "mysql -u root -p[Paswordofthedatabase] < restoresync.sql";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($qls);
    $rslt = $stmt->execute();
    echo"Base de Datos Restaurados/Importados Correctamente";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage;
}
?>
```

The problem is, it's not working, the console doesn't show any error message and so it does the PHP.

Is it even possible do this through a query? How can I do it? What is wrong with this code?

And is there any way to make sure than the backup would be created on a specific folder? Any suggestions, comments, request for clarification, questions or answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Ah, `mysqldump` and `mysql` are console commands, not SQL. Run them through [`exec()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or similar. It's worth specifying the full path, such as `/usr/bin/mysqldump`.

Comment: You'll have to do a search for how to supply a password on the console in an automated fashion for these (or maybe there is a console option, I forget). I think Ubuntu uses a utility to take a password for automated, console-less operations.

Comment: @halfer Any idea of one sql alternative or something? i'll try to do it through exec() too, or you can give an example to try it again through exec()?, i'm in windows

Thanks in advance

Comment: @halfter nevermind, i notice i was all the time try to use execute() instead of exec(), it works, if you want set it like a true answer and i'll choose it, for the points.

Thanks, it works!

Comment: Just use `exec()` around the commands you have now. I've just searched, and it does look like you can supply a password on the console - just be aware that other users on the machine may be able to see this, in their Task Manager.

Comment: (There is an answer to this effect now below, feel free to accept that one).

Answer (score 3):

Those are not MySQL queries but commands you execute through terminal.
Use this to execute the command and to get the **complete** output:

```
$dump_output = shell_exec("mysqldump --opt --default-character-set=UTF8 --single-transaction --protocol=TCP -u --user=root --password=dbpassword --host=localhost DB_NAME > restoresync.sql");
echo $dump_output; /* Your output of the dump command */

$restore_output = shell_exec("mysql -u root -p[Paswordofthedatabase] < restoresync.sql");
echo $restore_output; /* Your output of the restore command */
```

Instead of `shell_exec()` you can also use `exec()` like *halfer* mentioned.

The difference between them is that you get full output with `shell_exec()` and with `exec()` you get only the last line returned of the output.

Comment: The use of exec() and shell_exec(), both just create a .sql file than weight 0kb and than i can't use it to import, any suggestion in how to fix that?
also, it doesn't echo the information, in none of both cases, at least in the web page, any suggestions?, i know than i say than it was ready, but aparently it isn't, any idea, comment or question would be much apreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: its returning me this: "Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS] For more options, use mysqldump --help" Definetly its going there, i just take your code and refill the spaces and this i'm posting you here is what returns, still don't create the file, but is going there, can you tell me what are the options to make it work or where i can learn about them? thanks in advance :)